# Split delimited string into an array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'm trying to add an array. In one way it works the other does not, but I could not figure out what it is.

I'll explain:

WHILE MY AND LAY IN Implode

```
<?php $i = 1; $b = 0; do { ?>
   <td><?php echo $SubtraiMes[] = DemostrativoAno("financ_despesa",$ano,09) ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $SubtraiMes[] = DemostrativoAno("financ_despesa",$ano,10) ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $SubtraiMes[] = DemostrativoAno("financ_despesa",$ano,11) ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $SubtraiMes[] = DemostrativoAno("financ_despesa",$ano,12) ?></td>
<?php $MesSomado = implode(", ",tiraMoeda($SomaMes)); $i++;$b++; } while ($i <= $repetir); ?>
```

THE RESULT APPEARS SO

> 125.70, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 300.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 65.00, 0.00, 1825.70

LAY IN ARRAY E SOMO

```
<?php $MesSomado = array($MesSomado); echo array_sum($MesSomado); ?>
```

RESULT

> 0

BUT IF I DO SO, IT WORKS

```
<?php $MesSomado = array(125.70, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 300.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 65.00, 0.00, 1825.70); echo array_sum($MesSomado); ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: replace implode on explode

Comment: KoIIIeY - replace |> $MesSomado = implode(",",tiraMoeda($SomaMes)) <| to |> $MesSomado = explode(",",tiraMoeda($SomaMes)) <| ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If current value in `$MesSomado` is,

```
125.70, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 300.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 65.00, 0.00, 1825.70
```

Try,

```
<?php $MesSomado = explode(",",$MesSomado); echo array_sum($MesSomado); ?>
```

You can get the correct answer I think..